# Help understanding a paper on kernel density estimates

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

I want to calculate a KDE (Kernel Density Estimate) with a confidence band for some data. I am using [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/24709360.2017.1396742?needAccess=true) to learn how to do this. However, I am having difficulty understanding some parts of it. Do you mind helping me make sense of some of it?

- On page 167 it explains the difference between confidence intervals and confidence bands (see screenshot below). Do you know what the highlighted $K$ symbol denotes here?[image]
- Do you know what the $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ symbol denotes on the next page (see screenshot below)? [image]
- Below that it talks about using empirical bootstrap to generate bootstrap sample $X_1^*$, ..., $X_n^*$. Can you explain in more detail how this is done? Or link to something that explains it?

Comment: What is a KDE ?

Comment: Probably 'Kernel density estimation', but IMHO the question is confusing and unfocused.

Comment: Yes, KDE stands for kernel density estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\mathbb{K}$ is their notation for the support. c.f. p.177-178.
2. $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is standard notation for the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of a standard normal, i.e. satisfying $\Phi(z_{1-\alpha/2})=1-\alpha/2$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.
3. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Types_of_bootstrap_scheme) or [these MIT notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading24.pdf)

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful. I think I get it now. 

So provided you're only working with real numbers you could replace $\mathbb{K}$ with $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but do you know what the $I$ symbol denotes on page 169 in the equation that reads:
$$c_{1-\alpha,BT}(x)=\hat{G}_x^{-1}(1-\alpha),\ \ \ \ \hat{G}_x(t)=\frac{1}{B}\sum_{j=1}^BI(\Delta_j\le t).$$
Is $I(\Delta_j \le t)$ equivalent to $H(t - \Delta_j)$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function?

Comment: @Peanutlex I haven't read the paper in detail, but if the support is all reals, then sure, $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Peanutlex $I(A)$ is notation used for an indicator function, i.e. taking the value $1$ when condition $A$ is met, and $0$ otherwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function